# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(x+\sin x)}{\sin x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to evaluate $$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin (x+\sin x)}{\sin x}\,dx$$
I tried to expand $$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x\cos (\sin x)+\cos x\sin (\sin x)}{\sin x}\,dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\cos (\sin x)+\frac{\cos x\sin (\sin x)}{\sin x}\right)dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos (\sin x)\,dx+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin (\sin x)}{\sin x}\,d(\sin x)$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos (\sin x)\,dx+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos (\sin x)\,dx+\operatorname{Si}(1)$$
But I don't know what to do next, help me, thank you

Comment: Check bessel's function.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did is correct! Let me help you out a little bit.
The bessel function's integral representation is given by
$$J_n(z)=\frac1\pi \int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\cos(tn-z\sin t) dt$$
Thus,
$$J_0(1)=\frac1\pi \int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\cos(-\sin t) dt$$
$$J_0(1)=\frac2\pi \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(\sin t) dt$$

which gives your result by replacing variables
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(\sin x) dx = \frac{\pi}{2}J_0(1)$$

So, the final asnwer of your integral becomes
$$\boxed{\frac{\pi}{2}J_0(1)+ \text{Si}(1)}$$

Comment: I was curious so I [looked up](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Pi%2F2+BesselJ%5B0%2C+1%5D+%2B+SinIntegral%5B1%5D) the value: $2.148\,053$. The link also has some fun alternate representations.

Comment: Thank you very much!